# Import txt file and filter with space

Tags: python-3.x, repeat

I'm writing a script to track my orders from a website. I want to import the order# from a txt file and the script should repeat it self as long as there are ordernumbers.I wrote a code where the script imports this txt file and chooses a random ordernumber but the script puts all ordernumbers together and doesnt seperate them how can I fix this ?
this is my code:

```
f=open("Order#.txt", "r")
OrderNR = f.read()
words = OrderNR.split()
Repeat = len(words)
for i in range(Repeat):
    randomlist = OrderNR
    Orderrandom = random.choice(randomlist)
    Mainlink = 'https://footlocker.narvar.com/footlocker/tracking/startrack?order_number=' + Orderrandom
```

Comment: Please don't edit in new questions. If you have another question, post a new one. You can link to this one for context if you think it's necessary

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using f.read(), try using f.readlines().

```py
# Using readlines()
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
```

Comment: Hi it didn't worked for me with this code but I searched for an other readlines code and this one worked for me: lines = open('Order#.txt').read().splitlines()
    myline =random.choice(lines)

Answer (score 0):

Try `PANDAS`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Order#.txt', delimiter='\t')
print(df)
```

## you can see TXT file in table format